# Three-body problem with multiple systems?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, newtonian-gravity, orbital-motion, galaxies, three-body-problem

The three-body problem has been known for a long time (https://www.spacedaily.com/m/reports/On_chaos_drunks_and_a_solution_to_the_chaotic_three_body_problem_999.html), in which two celestial bodies are in orbit and when a third one is introduced, the orbits become chaotic and one of these bodies can be ejected.

As it is said, the orbital energy can be dissipated by tidal torques and gravitational waves, and presumably this would relax the orbits making them be closer to each other (hardening the orbit). However, it is also said that one of the bodies can be ejected with so much force that it can leave the system to never return.

Imagine that our ejected star gets ejected from the galaxy but after some time begins to be attracted again by it and by random change ends up in the same system. That celestial body would have gained kinetic energy as it is gravitationally attracted to the galaxy and the system. Could it be able to modify the hardened orbits of the original system and kick one (or all) of the celestial bodies again?